# How to add properties to ArrayLists that include inheritance?

Tags: java, arraylist, multiple-inheritance

I'm doing an assignment on inheritance and I have so far created a superclass a subclass. Within these classes, there are methods that have been added to define information such as an animal's name or age. Now I have been asked to do the following:

- Create a Demo class with a main method that creates an ArrayList of Animal objects. Fill the list with different animals, also with different names and ages.

I'm completely confused by this. If I try to create animals within my new ArrayList it tells me that the Animal class is abstract and cannot be instantiated. Here is the contents of the relevant classes:

**Animal class (super class)**

```
abstract public class Animal 
{

    int age;
    String name;
    String noise;

Animal(String name, int age)   
{
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
} 

Animal()
{

  this("newborn", 0);
}

abstract public void makeNoise();

public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
  public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

abstract public Food eat(Food x) throws Exception;

abstract public void eat(Food food, int count) throws Exception;


}
```

**Wolf class (sub class)**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Wolf extends Carnivore
{

            ArrayList<Food> foodGroup = new ArrayList<>();
String name;
int age;

Wolf(String name, int age)   
{  
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
Wolf()
{
  super();
}
    public void makeNoise()  
    {
        noise = "Woof!";
    }
    public String getNoise()  
    {
        return noise;
    }

    public Food eat(Food x) throws Exception
    { 
        if (x instanceof Meat) {
                return x;
            } else {
               throw new Exception("Carnivores only eat meat!");
            }
    }
public void eat(Food food, int count) {
    while (count > 0) {
        addFood(food);
        count--;
    }
}


public void addFood(Food inFood)
{
  foodGroup.add(inFood);
}
}
```

**Demo class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
                    ArrayList<Animal> animalGroup = new ArrayList<>();
     //Add new Animals with properties such as name and age?           
     Animal wolf1 = new Wolf();

    addAnimal(new Wolf("lnb1g16", 6));

    }

    public static void addAnimal(Animal inAnimal)
{
    animalGroup.add(inAnimal);
}

}
```

Apparently I'm suppose to create an array of Animals in the Demo class based off of these prior classes? I don't understand how this would be done and why I need to create a another main method either. Any help on how I would write the Demo class would be much appreciated as I'm confused by what I have been asked to do, thanks.

Comment: Does Carnivore extend Animal?  If so try to create a wolf and add it to your ArrayList - does it work?  If not what is the error?

Comment: Carnivore does extend Animal. When I create a new wolf object and then try to add it to the ArrayList like this `wolf1(new Animal("Wolf", 6));` I get the error "Animal is abstract, cannot be instantiated".

Comment: You have a Wolf class so shouldn't you do `new Wolf (....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo class

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
                ArrayList<Animal> animalGroup = new ArrayList<>();
 //Add new Animals with properties such as name and age?           
 Animal wolf1 = new Wolf();

animalGroup.add(new Wolf("sam", 5));
animalGroup.add(new Wolf("george", 5));
animalGroup.add(new Wolf("patrick", 7));

}
```

Comment: You needed to make a main method to actually instantiate all of the individual animals. The classes for the animals are like a blueprint and can't actually function until you build an animal based on that blueprint. The main method builds all the animals. Also you should only need one main method. You really shouldn't need any other methods at all in the demo class.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this made it easier to understand.